# Console App (.Net Standard) not listed

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and trying to create a "Console App (.Net Standard)".  It is no longer on my list of available projects when I do "File -> New Project..."

[image: options in Visual Studio]

It was there a few minutes ago.  It disappeared after I created a "Console App (.Net Core)" and then deleted that app because I realized I really wanted a Standard app.

I deleted it by removing it from Visual Studio, then going to the file system and deleting it.

I tried running the installer and updating the 2017 install.  That did not help.

How can I get "Console App (.Net Standard)" available as a project type to create?

[EDIT] I have shutdown and restarted visual studio.

[EDIT] I have attempted to run `devenv /installvstemplates` but the devenv command is not found.  I found it located here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`.  What is the preferred way to call it?  [add to path or some other way?]

[EDIT] I ran like this: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /installvstemplates` and got a `The operation could not be completed.  The requested operation requires elevation.`.

[EDIT] I ran like this: `runas /user:Administrator "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /installvstemplates` and got a `RUNAS` usage help message.

[EDIT] I ran the command in a powershell window with Administrator privilege and got this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv' /installvstemplates
At line:1 char:75
+ ... iles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv' /installv ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:75
+ ... \Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv' /installvstemplates
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'installvstemplates' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

[EDIT] found out that I need to run the quoted command prefixed with a &.  Now I can run devenv.

[EDIT] I decided I needed a "Console App (.Net Standard)" after posting this question: [Project Type for simple headless windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787278/project-type-for-simple-headless-windows-application)

Comment: Have you tried closing down your Visual Studio, open terminal as administrator (cmd), type: devenv /installvstemplates

Comment: I came here as well because VS2017 hides Framework Console App in "Get Started" meanwhile to create a dotnet core app, the most obvious process is "dotnet core" -> "console app"

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to create a .NET Standard console app.

You can think of .NET Standard like you would an interface in C#. .NET Standard is an interface, then there's concrete implementations of it in .NET Framework, .NET Core and other platforms. .NET Standard makes sense for class libraries, but a console app needs to actually run on a specific concrete implementation.

Thus, there is no Visual Studio project template for .NET Standard console apps. You can create a console app for .NET Framework or .NET Core and then consume .NET Standard class libraries.

Comment: Are you saying that when I previously saw "Console App (.Net Standard)" as an option it was just a figment of my imagination?   [I won't be insulted with an answer in the affirmative].

Comment: @MichaelPotter Perhaps. You may have seen Class Library .NET Standard and you're just remembering it wrong. Or perhaps at one point they had a template that actually used .NET Core or .NET Framework, even though it was labeled as .NET Standard. I don't know, but I have VS 2017 15.3 and the Desktop stack installed and I don't have a Console App .NET Standard template either.

Comment: Alright, I am questioning my sanity but I have no other explanation at this time.  I am going to give it a day to see if anyone has a better explanation and then give you the bounty.

Comment: But .net standard executables seem to run just fine under both .net framework and .net core. So it’s not like it doesn’t make sense to want to be able to do this. It just seems that [VS doesn’t know how to make both `Assembly.exe.config` and `Assembly.runtimeconfig.json` for the same output file](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/833#issuecomment-354187744). But it should work as long as your dependencies are pure and not substituted depending on your runtime target.

Comment: @binki And how did you create a .NET Standard executable?

Comment: @mason Create a “Class Library (.NET Standard)” project, make the modifications [suggested at this GitHub post](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/833#issuecomment-354187744), and add `<RunCommand>$(AssemblyName)$(TargetExt)</RunCommand>` to enable VS to run it via C-f5.

Comment: @binki if this works, you have saved the day my friend. I'm doing a data import and have 2 projects in the solution, one in .NET 4.5 and another in Core. I need to be able to talk to both of them.

Comment: @Varin then all you need is a .NET Standard class library you share between them. You don’t need to do what Binki said.

Answer (score 1):

My code looked like this

```cs
using System;
namespace TriNitroToluene
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

In the project properties, set output type to console application, and just change the extension to EXE. that's how it works!